# Angular, How to push id to an object for each row with formbuilder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-formbuilder

i cant push id to an object for each row with formbuilder.
So this is my form

```
     <form [formGroup]="add">
    <label for="name"> Name:
        <input id="name" type="text" formControlName="name">
    </label>
    <label for="email"> E-Mail:
        <input id="email" type="email" formControlName="email">
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(add.value)">add
    </button>
</form>
```

my row

```
                    <tr *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index; ">
                    <td>{{person.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{person.email}}</td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="deleteUser(i)">d
                    </button>
                </tr>
```

and i'm pushing my object to array like this way

```
onSubmit(value) {
    this.addToUsers(value);
  }

  addToUsers(person) {
    this.persons.push(person);
  }
```

So my question is, how to push unique id for each row to object and then show it in html with command `{{person.id}}`, within name and e-mail.
I'm using Angular 8.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in `onSubmit` you can generate a unique id and assign it to the person object then call `addToUsers` and push it to array

Answer (score 0):

Generate unique id using random function or date.

```
addToUsers(person) {
    person = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person));
    person.id = new Date().getTime();
    this.persons.push(person);
  }
```

Comment: tried and now every row has same id and changes on every click, when adding new object.

Comment: same problem in this link. all rows have same id and when i'm adding new one, every row change ids and it's same for all rows.

Comment: It was showing same id because of same reference of object with the form. Either reset the form - `this.add.reset` after adding row or change the reference using  `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person))`.

Answer (score 0):

In your form element, use the official ngSubmit binding if possible, here's the benefits as to why: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm

Sadly I think the only solution using template forms is to generate the ID. (see answer from Durgesh Pal)

But! A better solution to this would be to use ReactiveForms, they allow much more flexibility and you can directly identify the objects within the form (as you can literally use this.form.value and it'll give you an object of the current form back) - as well as generate forms from scratch purely via RxForm code. So I'd just like to suggest have a look at this too: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Hopefully this is helpful